# C++ Heap Overflow results in hardfault

Tags: c++

I was trying to test a heap overflow:
Therefore I'm adding lots of dummy elements to a vector.
My expectation: some sort of exception (bad alloc or something like that).

(since a vector is a contiguous memory area reallocations are likely to happen once the vector grows. I'm wondering how i could detect if adding an element worked.
According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/
push_back has no return value).

Additionally i have defined a custom termination handler. The custom termination handler is set **before**  the heap overflow is induced.

I'm setting my termination handler to a custom handler

```
void CFatal_Error::Set_Termination_Handler()
{
    set_terminate(Termination_Handler);
}

void CFatal_Error::Termination_Handler()
{
    // crash and stop here
    configASSERT(0);
}
```

The heap overflow is provoked by

```
vector<uint32_t> test;
try
{
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < UINT32_MAX; i++)
    {
        test.push_back(i);
    }
}
catch (const exception &ex)
{
    configASSERT(0);
}
```

First I'd expect that I'm running into the exception but instead I'm going directly to a hard fault. Could somebody explain this behaviour?

Compiler flags used:

```
Building file: ../Test_SD.cpp
Invoking: MCU G++ Compiler
\Debug
arm-none-eabi-g++ -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 '-D__weak=__attribute__((weak))' '-D__packed=__attribute__((__packed__))' -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F429xx -I"Inc" -I"Inc/User" -I"xxx/Inc/User/debug" -I"xxx/Inc/User/Testcases" -I"xxx/Inc/User/display" -I"xxx/Inc/User/SD" -I"xxx/Inc/User/SD/XML" -I"xxx/Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc" -I"xxx/Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy" -I"xxx/Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/portable/GCC/ARM_CM4F" -I"xxx/Middlewares/ST/STM32_USB_Device_Library/Core/Inc" -I"xxx/Middlewares/ST/STemWin/Config" -I"xxx/Middlewares/ST/STemWin/inc" -I"xxx/Middlewares/ST/STM32_USB_Device_Library/Class/CustomHID/Inc" -I"xxx/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include" -I"xxx/Middlewares/Third_Party/FatFs/src" -I"xxx/Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/include" -I"xxx/Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/CMSIS_RTOS" -I"xxx/Drivers/CMSIS/Include"  -g3 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++17 -ffunction-sections -c -fno-rtti -MMD -MP -MF"Src/User/Testcases/Test_SD.d" -MT"Src/User/Testcases/Test_SD.o" -o "Src/User/Testcases/Test_SD.o" "../Src/User/Testcases/Test_SD.cpp"
Finished building: ../Src/User/Testcases/Test_SD.cpp
```

Linker flags used

```
    Building target: xxx.elf
Invoking: MCU G++ Linker
arm-none-eabi-g++ -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -L"xxx\Middlewares\ST\STemWin\Lib"  -specs=nosys.specs -specs=nano.specs -u_printf_float -T"../STM32F429ZITx_FLASH.ld" -Wl,-Map=output.map -Wl,--gc-sections -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -o "Giessomat.elf" @"objects.list"  -lSTemWin540_CM4_OS_GCC -lm
Finished building target: Giessomat.elf

make --no-print-directory post-build
Generating binary and Printing size information:
```

**Edited Entry**

Comment: It seems like an [MCVE] is in order. What compiler and what compilation flags are you using?

Comment: What leads you to expect an exception on overflow? *I* would expect it to be Undefined Behaviour, but I didn't check the standard to verify thst.

Comment: how can i be sure not to run into unexpected behaviour because of to few free heap. How can i check if adding a vector element failed?

Answer (score 2):

You definitely won't get an exception as you compile with `-fno-exceptions`, which is quite normal for bare-metal applications like yours.

Comment: thx for the tip. I removed the fno-exceptions flag. (BTW for G++ you have to disable this in the compiler options AND linker options, I only did the first) But the general problem still exist. How can I tell whether a vector reallocation failed because of insufficient heap?. There must be a way?